# Session ID changes since VS2010SP1 / IE10 Preview installed

Tags: asp.net, sessionid, visual-studio-2010

I have a web application that can have addons installed. To create these addons I create a new web application with the same structure and reference the assembly from the main application.

After this I copy the aspx (markup) files only to the main application, so I have markup pages and a reference to the assembly so I can debug.

This has all been working fine up until just now when Im making amendments, the only thing that has changed since I last worked on it is the installation of VS2010 SP1.

Now there is a point in code - I cant see exactly where its happening as it external code but the session ID is changing and im loosing everything in session.

I have a piece of code to open a new window with a report:

```
        string link = String.Format( "window.open('{0}');", Page.ResolveUrl( "~/CustomPages/BudgetOnlineMedia.aspx" ) );

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this.GetType(), "MedReport", link, true );
```

after this a breakpoint gets hit in the base page:

```
/// <summary>
/// OnPreload
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">args</param>
[VersionChange( "7.3.88.272", "13/04/2011", "Fully qualified path to login page" )]
protected override void OnPreLoad( EventArgs e )
{
    try
    {
        base.OnPreLoad( e );

        if ( base.CurrentUser == null )
        {
            Response.Redirect( "~/Pages/Login.aspx", false );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        ErrorLogging.LogError( ex );
    }
}
```

The Same breakpoint gets hit again but this time the SessionID has changed!

I can read the callstack at this point but there is nothing in my code to change the session.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
>   Web.WAP.Objects.DLL!Web.WAP.Objects.Controls.UserPresencePage.OnPreLoad(System.EventArgs e) Line 28 C#
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0x22b bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0x84 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() + 0x51 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x16 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x32 bytes   
    App_Web_-ti4sydr.dll!ASP.custompages_budgetexhibition_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x33 bytes  C#
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0xb6 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) + 0x4c bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x133 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) + 0x7c bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x17c bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x63 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x47 bytes  
    WebDev.WebHost20.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process() + 0x177 bytes 
    WebDev.WebHost20.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection conn) + 0x6c bytes    
    [Appdomain Transition]  
    WebDev.WebHost20.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(object acceptedSocket) + 0xd3 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x2f bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x6f bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack) + 0x53 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(object state) + 0x59 bytes
```

What is [App Domain Transition]?

Can you see anything that would cause the session ID to change!?

EDIT:

ok, this may not be related to VS SP1 but IE10 preview.

Now when I do a window.ShowModalDialog, then from that dialog a window.open. Internet explorer creates a new session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this may not be related to VS SP1 but IE10 preview.

Now when I do a window.ShowModalDialog, then from that dialog a window.open. Internet explorer creates a new session

This seemed to be a bug in IE8 but it looks like it may be back in IE10.

This is a work around I had to use.

in my base page to show a modal dialog (which passes the window object)

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows a Page as a Modal dialog
/// </summary>
/// <param name="URL">The URL</param>
/// <param name="Width">The Width</param>
/// <param name="Height">The Height</param>
/// <param name="Resizable">Resizable?</param>
/// <param name="IfScript">Java script to run if the window returns true</param>
/// <param name="ElseScript">Java script to run if the window returns false</param>
protected void ShowModalDialog( string URL, int Width, int Height, bool Resizable, string IfScript, string ElseScript )
{
    try
    {
        string sModalDialog = @"
                                try
                                {{
                                    var args = new Object();
                                    args.window = window;
                                    if (window.showModalDialog('{0}', args, 'dialogHeight={1}px;dialogWidth={2}px;resizable={3}'))
                                    {{
                                        {4}
                                    }}
                                    else
                                    {{
                                        {5}
                                    }}
                                }}
                                catch (e)
                                {{
                                    alert(e.value);
                                }}";

        string vbs = String.Format( sModalDialog, URL, Height, Width, Resizable ? "yes" : "no", IfScript, ElseScript );

        base.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this.GetType(), "ModalDialog", vbs, true );
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

And the base Page method to open a popup window (which checks for a passed window object)

```
       /// <summary>
    /// Shows a Popup Window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Link">The link to show in the window</param>
    /// <param name="Width">The Width of the window</param>
    /// <param name="Height">The Height of the window</param>
    /// <param name="Name">The name of the window</param>
    /// <param name="ScrollBars">The Scroll bars to show</param>
    /// <param name="Resizable">Whether the window is resizable</param>
    /// <param name="ShowToolBar">Whether to show the toolbar</param>
    /// <param name="ShowStatusBar">Whether to show the status bar</param>
    /// <param name="ShowAddressBar">Whether to show the address bar</param>
    protected void OpenWindow( string Link, int Width, int Height, string Name, Sicon.API.Web.Enums.ScrollBars ScrollBars, bool Resizable, bool ShowToolBar, bool ShowStatusBar, bool ShowAddressBar )
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append( "try" );
            sb.Append( "{" );
            sb.AppendFormat( "Link='{0}';", Link );
            sb.AppendFormat( "Name='{0}';", Name.Replace( " ", "" ) );
            sb.Append( "    leftPos = 0;" );
            sb.Append( "    topPos = 0;" );
            sb.Append( "    if (screen) " );
            sb.Append( "    {" );
            sb.AppendFormat( "        leftPos = (screen.width / 2) - ( {0} / 2 );", Width );
            sb.AppendFormat( "        topPos = (screen.height / 2) - ( {0} / 2 );", Height );
            sb.Append( "    }" );
            sb.Append( @"
                        var myWindow = window;
                        if ((typeof(dialogArguments) !== 'undefined' && dialogArguments != null))
                        {
                            if (typeof(dialogArguments.window) !== 'undefined' && dialogArguments.window != null)
                            {
                                myWindow = dialogArguments.window;
                            }   
                        }
                        " );
            sb.AppendFormat( "    myWindow.open(Link,Name,'width={0},height={1},left=' + leftPos + ',top=' + topPos +' ", Width, Height );

            //Check whether to show Scroll Bars
            switch ( ScrollBars )
            {
                case Sicon.API.Web.Enums.ScrollBars.One:
                    sb.Append( ",scrollbars=1 " );

                    break;

                case Sicon.API.Web.Enums.ScrollBars.Two:
                    sb.Append( ",scrollbars=2 " );

                    break;
            }

            //Check whether the window is resizable
            if ( Resizable )
            {
                sb.Append( ",resizable " );
            }

            //Check Whether to show the toolbar
            if ( ShowToolBar )
            {
                sb.Append( ",toolbar " );
            }

            //Show the status bar
            if ( ShowStatusBar )
            {
                sb.Append( ", status " );
            }

            //Show the address bar
            if ( ShowAddressBar )
            {
                sb.Append( ", location " );
            }

            sb.Append( "');" );
            sb.Append( "}" );
            sb.Append( "catch (e)" );
            sb.Append( "{" );
            sb.Append( "    alert(e.value);" );
            sb.Append( "}" );

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this.GetType(), Name, sb.ToString(), true );

            sb = null;
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then in the page that opens the second window (call the base page methods)

```
    protected void btnBudgetOnlineMedia_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            base.OpenWindow( Page.ResolveUrl( "~/CustomPages/BudgetOnlineMedia.aspx" ),
                800,
                600,
                "Med Report", 
                API.Web.Enums.ScrollBars.Two,
                true,
                false,
                false,
                false );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogError( ex );
        }
    }
```

Note: Im calling window.open on the window object that is passed through from the dialogArguments.

This is horrible of course, has anyone got a better solution?

Information on this problem here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831678

UPDATE: It may also be related to the installation of IE10, looks like some of my internet security settings got reset and this was affecting javascript. The work around in code is also good to implement to avoid this in the future anyway.